# Phone stuck on bootloop ? HTC desire 826

Tags: boot

I tried to root my phone using twrp. after i rooted it using TWRP my phone isnt turning on... its stuck on boot logo (HTC)  I cant turn it off ? How can I turn it off ?

Edit : it's solved and the answer is down below.

Comment: Can you get into recovery?

Comment: No problem. It's solved now :)

Comment: Would you mind posting how you solved the problem as an answer?  It could help other users with similar problems.

Comment: Done, I'm not very good at English. But I tried my best. Links will be posted later

Comment: @IshanFdo1 Thanks for writing it up, but it's no use posting it as an edit to the question. You need to use the **Answer your own question** button below to post an answer. That way, when you're done, the question will show up as answered, and other users can vote up your answer to say thanks.

Comment: Done :) I posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. So here are the steps I did to fix my phone. First I turned off the phone by holding power button and volume up button at the same time. As soon as the screen turn off I quickly held the power button and volume down button to get into bootloader(if you don't get into bootloader as fast as u can. Phone will turn on again to normal boot and stuck there automatically). And then as I had already unlocked the bootloader and installed TWRP(there is info on how to unlock bootloader on HTC website, and u can find how to install TWRP a simple Google search), As I was too stupid not to backup my phone before trying to mess with the rooting. I had to download a TWRP backup from the internet (search google "HTC desire 826 megathread " there is a thread on XDA dev). I found a backup for TWRP for my phone and downloaded it. I connected my phone to PC while the phone was in TWRP menu. It gave me access to phone internal storage. First I made a backup in TWRP to find the location on backup files. Then I copied the files and saved it in the exact spot where the TWRP made the backup. I disconnected phone from my computer. And then clicked on "Restore" on my phone and accepted it. Then my phone worked fine after restoring the phone to a backup. So lesson learnt, always make a backup of your phone before messing with the ROM. I was stupid enough to think that everything will be okay when I was rooting the phone -_-